# How to Create an api for OrangeHRM

Tags: php, json, api, xml-rpc, orangehrm

I want to create an api for orangehrm to punch in & punch out but i am unable to find any documentation to create an api.

Anybody knows the standards or reference to create API for Orange HRM using XMLRPC,JSON etc..

Comment: Hello did you managed to create the API?

Comment: I would like to ask this too but for Mobile Apps (Android/iOS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a 4-page overview of its support for web services. Note the Web services controller on page 4.

http://web.archive.org/web/20110822071832/http://www.myplick.com/view/4LD-9rCeJwJ/OrangeHRM-architecture-For-Web-Services?

Since its PHP based you can use one of the following:

1. The [phpxmlrpc library](http://phpxmlrpc.sourceforge.net/)(used by Joomla) OR the [IXR library](http://scripts.incutio.com/xmlrpc/) (used by Wordpress)
2. Then Read on the [xmlrpc specification](http://xmlrpc.scripting.com/default.html)
3. Learn best practises from looking at the Joomla & Wordpress implementations. Security is very important

All the best!

**EDIT:**
There's also the built-in [PHP library](http://xmlrpc-epi.sourceforge.net/) that you can enable as an extension

Comment: myplick.com link redirects to scam site as of 3/11/2015

Comment: @StormRider01 I've noticed it. Thanks. Not much I can do though. Tried doing a cursory search for the presentation. Best I could do is get the Webarchive link that points to the original page, but I dont think you will have access to the presentation (you could try). Otherwise, pick the page's content as keywords to find the same presentation elsewhere.